# Parse JSON using NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, xml, json, nsurlconnection

I am using Bing Search API and able to successfully parse the xml but not JSON.Below is the code to both parse xml and JSON,when I nslog the output of the JSON it shows "null" I don't know how to proceed from here.

```
 -(void)searchBing:(NSString *)text{
    //NSString *query1 = @"San Francisco Baseball";
    NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"'%@'",text];

    //NSString *query = query1;
    NSString *format = @"atom";
    NSString *market = @"'en-us'";
    //NSInteger top = 2;

    NSMutableString *fullURL = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:256];
    [fullURL appendString:URL];
    [fullURL appendFormat:@"Web?$format=%@", format];
    [fullURL appendFormat:@"&Query=%@",
     [query stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [fullURL appendFormat:@"&Market=%@",
     [market stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
   // [fullURL appendFormat:@"&$top=%d", top];

    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:
                                   [self getRequest:fullURL] delegate:self];
    if (connection)
    {
        NSLog(@"Connection established");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Connection failed");
    }
}
```

Below where am parsing both *xml*(successful) and *JSON*(unsuccessful)

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    // The request is complete and data has been received
    // You can parse the stuff in your instance variable now
    // convert to JSON
    NSLog(@"Finished loading: Received %d bytes of data",[self.responseData length]);
    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData: self.responseData];
    [parser setDelegate: self];
    [parser parse];

    NSLog(@"XMl == %@",parser);


    NSError *myError = nil;
    NSDictionary *res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.responseData options:kNilOptions error:&myError];

    NSLog(@"json data = %@",res);//getting null

}
```

Am using Base_64 encoding and to all viewers nothing wrong with query because getting correct information via xml parser.But I want response in *JSON*.

Structure sample

```
{
   "SearchResponse":{
      "Version":"2.2",
      "Query":{
         "SearchTerms":"testign"
      },
      "Spell":{
         "Total":1,
         "Results":[
            {
               "Value":"testing"
            }
         ]
      },
      "Web":{
         "Total":5100,
         "Offset":0,
         "Results":[
            {
               "Title":"Testign part 2 - Tiernan OTooles Programming Blog",
               "Description":"If this works, it means nothing really, but i have managed to build a .TEXT blog posting app. could be handy if i move my main blog to .TEXT, which i am thinking about..",
               "Url":"http:\/\/weblogs.asp.net\/tiernanotoole\/archive\/2004\/09\/24\/233830.aspx",
               "DisplayUrl":"http:\/\/weblogs.asp.net\/tiernanotoole\/archive\/2004\/09\/24\/233830.aspx",
               "DateTime":"2008-10-21T05:08:05Z"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: you check if the data is null as well?

Comment: same data is visible through xml but not through json

Comment: it's very strange because if the data is good you have to have for sure a json parse, can you give me the link that give you the JSON?

Comment: I afraid not possible because u need api key[of bing] to view.But my question is the parsing is done correctly?

Comment: yes but you can check for me if return a json and write the scructure?

Comment: I have uploaded the sample structure..

Comment: What does `NSLog(@"Error: %@", [myError description])` show?

Comment: Actually no error.It doesn't go into that condition because the dictionary value return null.I have also used this but no use  if (error) NSLog(@"[%@ %@] JSON error: %@", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), error.localizedDescription);

Comment: Does the string value of the data show the expected JSON?

Comment: @AaronBratcher I didn't get u can u explain it

Comment: NSString *json = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];    NSLog(json);   Is the proper json logged?

Comment: hey I used the above line code of code am getting some output[string] but not json.How to produce json??Am getting output with in tags[html or xml].

Comment: OK... this means that your self.responseData is not holding a JSON value and you have to do some more debugging. How is this populated? I also see you are trying to parse XML and JSON from the same self.responseData. That isn't possible.

Comment: Any idea why it is not holding because am appending the data.And it is of type NSMutableData(Strong). I tried to parse one at a time even though the JSON output was null.But XML did work.

Answer (score 0):

From your post:

```
 NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData: self.responseData];
.
.
.
 NSDictionary *res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.responseData options:kNilOptions error:&myError];
```

It looks like you're trying to use the same data as XML and JSON. You can't do that. The data returned from the server is in one form OR the other. It won't be both.

Comment: now I have only  NSString *json = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
    NSError *myError = nil;
    
    NSDictionary *res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.responseData options:kNilOptions error:&myError];
    NSLog(@"json data = %@",json);
    
    NSLog(@"\n\n\n\n\n\n data = %@",res);

Comment: Am sorry am not able to present the code in a better way like u did.